# How do home computer buses electrically put data on the wire?

Tags: pci-express, pci, isa

In particular I'd like to know what schemes PCI Express, PCI and ISA use at the physical layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're all different. You can easily look up each one. [PCI Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#Physical_layer) uses low-voltage differential signalling. [PCI](http://www.techfest.com/hardware/bus/pci.htm#1.0) uses both 5 volt and 3.3 volt signalling levels. [ISA](http://www.controlled.com/pc104faq/PC104SpecV2_5.pdf) uses simple TTL signalling.

Comment: so 1 and 0 zero are resp. coded as 5 V and 0 V signal levels in pci?

Comment: PCI supports both 5V and 3.3V signalling. Most likely, the actual signalling rules are something like: For 5V signalling, 0 is less than .7 volts, 1 is more than 3 volts. For 3.3V signalling, 0 is less than .3 volts, 1 is more than 2 volts.

Comment: wow, the ISA spec fits on a couple of pages.  I wonder what the PCIe spec is in kilo grams.

Comment: Regarding differential signaling:  Is there a direct mapping of the levels of the regenerated difference signal onto 0 and 1 as with the unipolar scheme in PCI and ISA?

Comment: The typical setup is that at least a .247 volt difference is required to indicate a legal value. The maximum a driver is permitted to output is a .454V difference. The average voltage of both differential outputs remains between 1.125V and 1.375V. Which line is at a higher voltage than the other determines if it's a 1 or a 0. (Of these buses, PCI-Express is the only one that is serial and the only one that uses differential signalling. You may need to double-check these values against different versions of PCI-Express, but it's about right.)